# How to map datatable columns to properties of DTO object of Type T

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, mapping, dto

How can map datatable columns with the properties of DTO object of Type T using LINQ query or Lambda expression. This should automatically map with any DTO. If there is a way to do this without hardcoding of column names of datatable

```
DataTable dt = db.GetEmployees();


foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    var obj = new T();
    PropertyInfo[] prop  = obj.GetType().GetProperties();



    var results = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => new T
        {
            ///How to directly map type T properties in prop with columns in datatable dt

        FirstName = ?

        //Expecting something like this
                //FirstName = columnName of dt here

        }     
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid using reflection?

Comment: @LawrenceZahner It's okay to use reflection. I just want to avoid properties row by row foreach manually and hardcoding for column names in the datatable

Comment: Ok, that opens up some possibilities. Are the column names of the DataTable an exact match to the property names in T?

Comment: Its not an exact match for instance `Property name = PhoneNumber , Column Name = Phone Number (WorkPhone)`

Comment: an alternate which I have not explored (so cant say if it definitely works) is the automapper library, its good for mapping, just not sure if it works for datatable to objects

Answer (score 1):

We can use reflection to convert the data table columns into a DTO object's property. In my case I was actually converting it into a List, here's the code:

```
        private IEnumerable<T> ConvertToEnumerable(DataTable dt)
        {
            List<T> ls = new List<T>();

            // get all the column names from datatable
            var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList();

            //dto so all properties should be public
            var dtoProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(); 

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                // create  a new DTO object
                var item = new T();

                // for each property of the dto
                foreach (var property in dtoProperties)
                {
                    var objPropName = property.Name;

                    // I am using the column map dictionary to convert the 
                    // DTO property name into my datatable column name
                    // but you can omit this step if your names in DTO 
                    // and datatable columns are same
                    var dbPropName = ColumnMap[property.Name];
                    if (columnNames.Contains(dbPropName))
                    {
                        if (row[dbPropName] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            // set the value
                            property.SetValue(item, row[dbPropName], null);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // add the DTO to the list
                ls.Add(item);
            }
            return ls;
        }
```

Do note that since we are doing `new T()`, the constraint on class is required for this. The constraint and the definition of columnMap for completeness is:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : new()
    {
        private DbManager context = null;

        public Dictionary<string, string> ColumnMap { get; set; }
        ...
        ...
     }
```

And the column name mappings are stored as:

```
public class RepositoryMap
{

    public static Dictionary<string, string> ObjectToDatatableMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        // keep in mind that key is the DTO property
        // value is the datatable columm name
        {"Id", "ID"},
        {"Owner", "OWNER"},
        {"QueryName", "QUERY NAME"},
        {"PhoneNumber", "Phone Number"},
    };
}
```

Comment: how the ColumnMap is done? Are you hardcoding the column names or how can it be handled. If possible please help with some sample code how the mapping is done without hardcoding

Comment: @user1030181 You will have to hardcode that mapping somewhere, in my case I choose to create a columnMap dictionary, you can make a rule based system as well but that is still hard-coding. A simple rule is to remove underscore from the datatable column name, you will have to manually create the set of rules and run the conversion.

Comment: Can you please post me the sample code of your dictionary

Comment: @user1030181 posted

Comment: So is it possible with LINQ query?

Comment: @user1030181 I don't think LINQ is suited for this, given the wide range of things you would be handling, conversion, edge cases where column name might not exist in DTO, etc.