# Using reflection for model creation - Any alternatives?

Tags: c#, reflection

I know there are tons of documents/blogs/discussions on how bad reflection is.
Knowing that, let's move forward to the scenario:

Say we have a data-table/cursor (yes, those are still used).
Now say, this has to be converted into a strongly types list of objects.

**Option 1**

Loop through the entire cursor/data table & manually assign everything to the instance of a
class, and finally add that object to a list/collection.

**Option 2**

Have a method with a Generic class parameter and use reflection to generate the object of that
class type.

ex.

```
var myList = convertDataTableToList<MyClass>(dataTable)
```

In this scenario, what are the disadvantages of reflection ?

Are there any alternatives to this approach (option 2) to achieve the same result?

My question is not language specific.

Note: The code example is in C#.net

Comment: I have removed unrelated tags as you said your question is `c#` specific. Do note that incorrect tags could attract downvotes and your question would likely receive less atention.

Comment: Reflection isn't bad -- *naive* uses of reflection are bad. Reflection and code generation are the bread and butter of well performing, excellent solutions like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) and [AutoMapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). What is true is that writing clear, fast code that uses reflection is hard, but library authors have done the heavy lifting for you. Conversely, `DataTable` involves no reflection but is a performance trap, because of how big a memory hog it is with larger data sets -- that's the penalty for being able to store "anything".

Comment: If you do use reflection, you should cache the types to avoid the performance issues of reflection (eg. dont use gettype/typeof in a loop without having a static dictionary). That being said, it is fine using it. This question [does what you are asking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56050972/2265446)

Comment: Also, though a little-used feature nowadays, you can actually have Visual Studio generate typed data sets (with `DataAdapters`) to read data in typed data tables. If you are already wedded to data tables and have no incentive to move away from them, it's worth considering over reading data in a table, then converting it, which pretty much nets you the worst of both worlds.

Comment: The problem is the size of the codebase. Something written long ago using a data table (throughout the project), moving away is not easy, as that will mean changes throughout the project. Also, for features being implemented now, I see no reason to read from datatable(for everything, everytime). Hence the question. Thanks for your insight though. I totally agree on memory issues of DT that you pointed out.

Comment: You can actually use Dapper with `DataTable`s, if you want -- there is a `DataTableReader` class that exposes `DataTable` as a `DbDataReader`, and Dapper can map objects from any reader (`IDataReader.GetRowParser`). It's a little roundabout, but the important thing is that it eliminates having to write the boilerplate of mapping classes from rows.